# Smallest non-isomorphic graphs with the same characteristic polynomials of their laplacian matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, graph-laplacian

For isomorphic graphs, the characteristic polynomials of their laplacian matrices coincide, but the converse is
 not true. The characteristic polynomial of the laplacian matrix does not uniquely
 identify the graph.

> What are the smallest non-isomorphic graphs with coinciding characteristic polynomials
>      of their laplacian matrices ?

Comment: What do you mean by the "the least non-isomorphic graphs"?  Do you mean the graphs with the smallest number of vertices?

Comment: Yes, exactly that. And if the number of vertices coincide, the one with the smaller number of edges is the smaller. I edited the question because of the unlucky word "least"

Comment: There are a few of size $7$ in [this paper](http://user.math.uzh.ch/halbeisen/publications/pdf/spec.pdf)

Comment: One of the graphs in the given example has a double edge. Can this be transformed to a simple graph with the same spectrum ?

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: I am surprised though, that $7$ vertices are already enough for isospectral non-isomorphic graphs.

Comment: I don't know enough about this to be surprised :P If you don't get any results here after a while, you might want to post this to Math Overflow.  I wouldn't be surprised if the answer isn't known; spectral graph theory hasn't been around for all that long.

Comment: Note that an "isospectral" pair could also refer to graphs where the spectrum of the adjacency matrix is identical.  The smallest such pair has apparently been [known](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CospectralGraphs.html) since 1990.

Comment: The laplacian matrix measures the connectivity, so there should be much less examples. But interesting enough that only $5$ nodes are sufficient in the case of adjacency matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a pair of Lapcian cospectral graphs on six vertices. See http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~fkenter/cospectral_talk.pdf